# Late initialisation of RegionBootstrap

Tags: android, altbeacon, android-ibeacon

In the reference application, RegionBootstrap is initialised in a **custom application class** on it's **onCreate method** and of course, the application class is called before any activity is called.

Is there a way to initialise RegionBootstrap inside an activity? I already tried making a static variable of RegionBootstrap so i can call it in a different activity, but unfortunately, it doesn't work.

```
BeaconApplication.regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap((BootstrapNotifier) this.getApplication(), downloadedBeacons);
```

The **Regions** I needed to be initialised will come from a server, so initialisation of RegionBootstrap must not come from the application class.

*** EDIT ***

```
public class LoginActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    …
    /*** short version ***/
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        /*** after successful login ***/
        BeaconApplication.beacons = downloadBeaconsFromServer();    
    }
}

public class BeaconActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    …
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        …
        startService(new Intent(this, BeaconService.class));
    }
}
```

This is where I implemented `BeaconConsumer`

```
public class BeaconService extends Service implements BeaconConsumer {
    private BeaconManager beaconManager;
    private BeaconNotifier beaconNotifier;
    private RegionBootstrap regionBootstrap;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate");
        beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
        beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));
        beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(1001);
        beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(101);
        beaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(101);
        beaconManager.setForegroundBetweenScanPeriod(1001);
        beaconNotifier = new BeaconNotifier(this);
        beaconManager.bind(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
        beaconManager.setMonitorNotifier(beaconNotifier);
        monitorBeacons();

        regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(beaconNotifier, BeaconApplication.beacons);
    }

    private void monitorBeacons() {
        for (Region beacon : BeaconApplication.beacons) {
            try {
                Log.i(TAG, "Monitoring beacon " + beacon.getUniqueId());
                beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(beacon);
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Monitoring beacon failed");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Implementation of `BeaconNotifier`

```
public class BeaconNotifier implements BootstrapNotifier {
    private Context context;

    public BeaconNotifier(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    didEnter.. etc

    @Override
    public Context getApplicationContext() {
            return context;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
BeaconManager.setMonitorNotifier(MonitorNotifier);
BeaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(Region);
```

But do not forget, in order to use `BeaconManager` methods, you have to wait until `BeaconService` is connected. Be aware, with this methods, you need to create your own service if you want to monitor beacons even if app is killed.

Btw, I remember, once I have also faced a problem with `RegionBootstrap`. I used a trick to handle that problem. Can you test following code?

```
...
BeaconManager.bind(yourConsumer);
...
//wait until BeaconConsumer.onBeaconServiceConnect() is called
//write following code inside of onBeaconServiceConnect
RegionBootstrap dummy = new RegionBootstrap(mBootstrapNotifier, new Region("dummy", null, null, null));
dummy.disable();
//after this point you can create your own RegionBootstrap
```

There is a key point in here, you need to create your own `BootstrapNotifier`. If you are doing this in an activity, you can do this:

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity implements BootstrapNotifier {
    ...
    BootstrapNotifier mBootstrapNotifier = this;
    ...
```

Or in an `Application` class:

```
public class YourApp extends Application implements BootstrapNotifier {
    ...
    BootstrapNotifier mBootstrapNotifier = this;
    ...
```

In my case, I have created an adapter and that adapter requires `Context`in its constructor and I have used that adapter as `BootstrapNotifier`:

```
public class AltBeaconAdapter implements BootstrapNotifier {
    private Context mContext;
    ...

    public AltBeaconAdapter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public Context getApplicationContext() {
        return mContext;
    }

    ...
}
```

Also, you have to implement `MonitorNotifier` methods since `BootstrapNotifier` is a sub class of `MonitorNotifier`.

Yes, this trick is weird and it shows there is an error in the library with initializing `RegionBootstrap` but I have service so I switched to first method that I proposed to you. If this trick works for you too, let me know so that I can create an issue on the library's GitHub page.

Comment: Will those methods open the app from the background and monitor the beacons even after android kills the app same as stated here? 
http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/resume-after-terminate.html

Comment: I have updated my answer, Please check it and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: RegionBootstrap needs two arguments, not just the Region as stated in my question. I tried this `RegionBootstrap dummy = new RegionBootstrap((BootstrapNotifier) getApplicationContext(), new Region("dummy", null, null, null));` but I got this error _java.lang.ClassCastException: com.tektosworld.ibeaconmobileapp.BeaconApplication cannot be cast to org.altbeacon.beacon.startup.BootstrapNotifier_. This is the same error I'm having when I don't put the BootstrapNotifier inside the Application class.

Comment: Sorry, that was my bad. Again I have updated my answer. I hope this time it will help you :). Btw, `RegionBootstrap` requires a `BootstrapNotifier` and you are supplying only an `Application` object which causes `ClassCastException`. You should implement `BootstrapNotifier` in your `com.tektosworld.ibeaconmobileapp.BeaconApplication` class. Let me know if I can help you more.

Comment: Does implementing BootstrapNotifier means that I should not implement BeaconConsumer anymore? Also, if I implement BootstrapNotifier in a service will this change anything?

Comment: Sorry I'm really confused. You said first that I should wait for `BeaconConsumer.onBeaconServiceConnect()` before creating a dummy RegionBootStrap. This means that I should implement **BeaconConsumer** right? Then I have to implement a **BootstrapNotifier**. But this would create two MonitorNotifier right?

Comment: Actually, If you are going to only monitor `Region`s, `RegionBootstrap` and `BootstrapNotifier` should be sufficient but I tried it before and it was problematic for me for late initialization. In my case I was also ranging beacons so I had to use `BeaconManager` and `BeaconConsumer`. If you do only wish to monitor regions, you can try without `BeaconManager` and create a dummy and disable it before creating the real one. Btw, If you can post your code here or related piece of it I can help you more. And also sorry for confusion.

Comment: I also need to range. In your AltBeaconAdapter, getApplicationContext() will return a Context not a BootstrapNotifier. So `RegionBootstrap dummy = new RegionBootstrap((new AltBeaconAdapter(this)).getApplicationContext(), new Region("dummy", null, null, null));` will still cause `ClassCastException`. I now implement BootstrapNotifier in a normal Class (not extending anything), so I think my code is somehow similar to your AltBeaconAdapter. Where do you call your AltBeaconAdapter constructor?

Comment: You need to do `RegionBootstrap dummy = new RegionBootstrap((new AltBeaconAdapter(this)), new Region("dummy", null, null, null));`. But, If you are going to use an adapter, keep its reference do not give it like that. You can use this Adapter anywhere at anytime. I am using it in my service and initializing it at its constructor but there is no place limit for initialization.

Comment: No errors but the app didn't detected the beacons after a restart. Where should I put a reference of the RegionBootstrap dummy? Should I save it in the Application class? In my code, it is saved in a service.

Comment: You don't need to save the dummy reference. I meant reference of  `(new AltBeaconAdapter(this))` object since you will need it again. I think you forget to reinitialize your real `RegionBootstrap` after a restart. It is too hard to help you without seeing any of your code.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I edited my question to post also some parts of my code. Hope this is clearer now. Thanks Furkan

Comment: Can you also write content of the `monitorBeacons();` method in `BeaconService`s `onBeaconServiceConnect()`?

Comment: It can detect beacons, but after a restart or a force kill, it stops working.

Comment: Yes, your code looks like valid but there is a problem with `RegionBootstrap` initialization. Since you are doing in a **service**, in order to re-initialize after app is killed, you need to restart your service as well. To do that, you need to persist your `Region`s as soon as you get them and retrieve them next time you start your service. Also you need to start your service in your `Application` class so that service can restart beacon scan after a kill. Btw, 101 milliseconds is to short for beacon scan, look at [this](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/battery_manager.html)

Comment: I'll try doing this and update you later. Thanks. Also I posted this problem in github. https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/issues/137#issuecomment-77150090

Comment: It's still not working. I already have a function that saves the beacons in sqlite database, So what I only did is load the beacon list to BeaconApplication.beacons from db, then move the startService from Activity to the my Application class

Comment: Did you check that your service is started at `BeaconApplication` properly? Or even your `BeaconApplication` is created after a kill command?

Comment: More basic approach is to add some logs at `BeaconApplication`s `onCreate` and `BeaconService`s `onCreate`. Even maybe more where you want to see what is going on.

Comment: That's what I did, but I can't see any output from my app.

Comment: This is what I did to start my service in `Application` class: `Intent intent = new Intent(this, BeaconService.class); startService(intent); bindService(intent, this, Activity.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);`. For me, it was enough to restart my service.

Comment: bindService's second paramater needs to be an android.content.ServiceConnection.

Comment: Yes, my `Applcation` class implements it.

Comment: I see. What are the things needed to be added inside the onServiceConnected/disconnected?

Comment: Dude! It's working! Only after a restart though, when the app is force killed, it still doesn't detect any beacon. Is that normal with the current module?

Comment: In order to restart your service after its killed, you need to add or replace following code to your `BeaconService`: `@Override public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) { return START_STICKY; }`

Comment: Yes, I already have that in my code from the start. It doesn't work though.

Comment: It seems like problem with the service. For me, it works the way I told you but I only tried to kill app via app switcher (in my case it is enough).

Comment: Should I initialise `beaconManager` in `onStartCommand` rather than `onCreate`? Do you think the problem relates to that?

Comment: Nope. It seems like your service is not sticky. Since you are not using `RegionBootstrap` in your `Application` class, you need to deal with the service operations like restarting it after a kill command.

Comment: How would I do that? I was looking for how services are restarted after it has been killed, but I read that it's impossible because of security reasons.

Comment: As far as I heard, there are workarounds by `BroadcastReceiver` with some certain events like `BOOT_COMPLETED`, `ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED`, `ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED` and etc but I am not sure and also as you said because of security issues and respect to owner of the device, you probably should let it go :). You can check `BroadcastReceiver`s though. Let me know if you find anything usefull about this topic.

Comment: Isn't that the task of the library? It will be redundant if I implement it again. The library works with phone restart and app switcher. But not when I forced kill it. The reference app works with all three situations.

Comment: Result of the reference app is actually weird, it shouldn't work when you force kill it. Even in libraries documentation it says in this way.